# Save an object from pandas_datareader into a csv file in Python 3.5

Tags: python, csv

In order to save stock prices from yahoo into Python 3.5, I use the pandas module :

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader

symbols = ['AAPL','MRK']

pnls = {i:dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','2010-01-01','2016-09-01') for i in symbols}
```

It creates two "tables" (I don't know the name, sorry), one for each share (here 'AAPL' and 'MRK'). I want to save each table into a csv file but I don't know how. Anyone does?

Thanks,

Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this:

```
from pandas_datareader import data as dreader


symbols = ['AAPL','MRK']
for i in symbols:
    dreader.DataReader(i,'yahoo','2010-01-01','2016-09-01').to_csv(i+'.csv')
```

It saves your data to two csv files.

It actually returns a `pandas` `DataFrame`. You can easily put a `pandas` `DataFrame` to csv file using the `to_csv` method.